# Identify this flower

Tags: identification, flowers

[image: This] flower blooms once in a year, in the winters.

The plant is only like 50 cm tall now, has no other branch and those few leaves you can see around the flower are the only leaves of the entire plant.

Now I saw two other branch like stuff near the [image: bottom].

What is this plant or name of the flower ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be Adenium obesum,common name desert rose - the bulbous shape of the base gives it away. It comes in a range of flower colours, and the shoots you  can see near the base are just that, new shoots. Their presence might indicate less than perfect growing conditions - you don't say where you are or whether this plant is in a pot or in the ground, which is quite important to know to make any more comment in regard to growing conditions.

Often grown as a houseplant, and the instructions in this link https://www.thespruce.com/grow-desert-rose-plants-indoors-1902974 are intended for plants grown in this manner, though it does contain information in regard to what conditions the plant prefers.

Comment: Google images of dessert rose shows images like this one..This is dessert rose then...well it is in a pot.

Comment: Ah... then following some of the instructions in  the link might be useful. Maybe it needs repotting if it hasn't been for some time - restriction at the root will slow growth down to barely surviving level, and that would explain the  new shoots low down.